# Как занести данные в БД при авторизации?

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Все заносится правильно кроме `user_id`.

```
login.php 
logged_in_redirect();

    $id = $_POST['user_id'];
      $username =$_POST['username'];
        $ip = GetRealIp($_POST['ip']);
        $date = date("Y-m-d");

        $query = "INSERT INTO `ipadress` (`user_id`,`username`,`date`, `ip`) 
          VALUES ('$id','$username','$date', '$ip')";
       $result2 = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: А пробовали перед выполнением запроса, вывести его на экран (echo $query;)?

Comment: Попробуйте:

    // ...
    echo $query;
    exit();
    $result2 = mysql_query($query);

Comment: Уважаемый, уберите переадресацию на index.php.

Comment: Переадресацию, если она нужна, делайте только в случае успешного запроса:

    $result2 = mysql_query($query);
    if($result2) {
        // переадресация
    } else {
        // ловим баги
    }

> просто белый экран

Значит какое-то условие не выполнилось и дело до запроса не дошло

Comment: если сделать вот так logged_in_redirect();

    $date = date("Y-m-d");

    $query = "INSERT INTO `ipadress` (`date`) 
      VALUES ('$date')";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query);то оно добавляет только ДАТУ!
а экран по прежднему белый!

Comment: Попробуйте сделать echo (int)$result2 = mysql_query($query);
А exit() убрали?

Comment: @LLIAKAJI,  Хм... А что у вас делает функция **logged_in_redirect()**?

Comment: exit(); теперь убрал, уже не белый экран, а фон сайта и прочее, но по echo (int)$result2 = mysql_query($query); ничего не имеется

Comment: function logged_in_redirect() {
if (logged_in()===true){
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}
}

если логин и пароль правильный то авторизация проходит,
разве что оттуда не убрал переадресацию, но оно туда не адресуется пока я ничего не трогаю!

Comment: а код формы моно глянуть? может вы в названиях полей намудрили?

Comment: форма как форма, 
<div class="widget">
<h2>login/registration</h2>
<div class="inner">
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<ul id="login">
<li>username:<br>
<input type="text" name="username">
</li>
<li>
password:<br>
<input type="password" name="password">
</li>
<li>
<input type="submit" value="enter">
</li>

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте добавить до этого всего

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

А может так красивее?

```
logged_in_redirect();

if (!empty($_POST['user_id']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['ip'])) {
    $id = (int) $_POST['user_id'];
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ip']);
    $date = date("Y-m-d");

    $query = "INSERT INTO `ipadress` (`user_id`, `username`, `date`, `ip`) 
      VALUES ($id, $username, $date, $ip)";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query);
}
```

Совет: Прочитайте про [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: оно может и красивее но ничего не поменялось!

Comment: Что возвращает mysql_query($query)?
Какие ошибки выводятся после вставки error_reporting(E_ALL) до всего этого?

Comment: ничего не выводится сразу переадресовывается в index.php а в таблице ipadress ничего не добавляется